# Error in findViewById tried everything

Tags: java, android, findviewbyid

```
public class fingerp  extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fingerp, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

This id for tabbed view with buttons

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File myDir = new File(root + "/documents");

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myDir.mkdirs();
    EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String edt = edit.getText().toString();
    File file = new File (myDir,edt);
}
```

this is for saving a folder in external storage in android and i am taking folder name input from user and to use that i am using this statement ↓

```
EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
String edt = edit.getText().toString();
```

but findViewById is giving an error

Comment: please post error stacktrace

Comment: Post your error log please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `findViewById()` is not implemented in class `Fragment`. That method is implemented for `Activity` or `View`

So, try the change below:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    EditText edit = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText);
    ....
}
```

**UPDATE**

As well commented below, you can not rely on `findViewById()` during `onCreate` method to find Views from Parent Activity. This is also marked in the [DOCS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)):

> Note that this can be called while the fragment's activity is still in the process of being created. As such, you can not rely on things like the activity's content view hierarchy being initialized at this point. If you want to do work once the activity itself is created, see onActivityCreated(Bundle).

This way, if your `EditText` is part of the `R.layout.fragment_fingerp`

You can do:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fingerp, container, false);

    EditText edit = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String edt = edit.getText().toString();
    File file = new File (myDir,edt);

    return rootView;
}
```

Or just move your code from `onCreate()` to `onActivityCreated` :

```
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...              
    EditText edit = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Note that during onCreateView I'm saving mRootView... not rootView... I added a second option anyway. Check the answer again

Comment: got it in option 2

Comment: I don't think so. Activity is set during onAttach (which is called before onCreate).

Comment: @W0rmH0le got it, I remove my comment. Anyhow, Mike's note still valid.

Comment: @Lino Thank you both for feedback. I was not aware about it and I changed my answer based in your comments. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you for the feedback.. I updated my answer based on your comments.. Thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 0):

Move your code from `onCreate` to `onViewCreated` which is specifically a Fragment life-cycle callback.